# ngIf: async inside ngIf template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Angular : 11.0.2
(simplified example to show my issue)

I have some problems using `async` pipe inside `ngIf` template (my data are not well refreshed). I write an easy example to expose my problem.

[Plunker code here](https://plnkr.co/edit/xat7ujR8s9iDVMoP)

**Steps to reproduce:**

- click `add` multiple times
- click `toggle`
- `data$ | async` displays `defaultValue` instead of `myArray` values (**not expected**)
- click `add`
- `data$ | async` is refreshed and displays `myArray` values (**expected**)
- click 2 times `toggle`
- `data$ | async` displays `defaultValue` again (**not expected**)

It looks like ngIf stores the data$ initial values on first ngOnInit. Why `{{data$ | async | json}}` returns the default value of `myArray` when `ngIf` block is toggled (even if `myArray` has changed).

**How can I handle this case using `rxjs` and `ngIf` ?**

Template:

```
<button (click)="add()">+ add</button>
<button (click)="sub()">- sub</button>
<button (click)="toggle()">toggle</button>

myArray={{myArray.value | json}}
length={{myArray.length}}

<div *ngIf="showMe">
  Inside ngIf:<br>
  data={{data$ | async | json}}<br>
  myArray={{myArray.value | json}}
</div>
```

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit,ChangeDetectorRef } from "@angular/core";
import { FormArray, FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms";
import {  combineLatest, Observable, of  } from "rxjs";
import { filter, map, startWith, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "src/app.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  showMe = false;
  form: FormGroup;
  x: number = 0;
  data$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private cd: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      myArray: this.fb.array(['defaultValue'])
    }) ;

    this.data$ = this.myArray.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(this.myArray.value));
  }

  add() {
    this.myArray.push(this.fb.control(this.x++));
  }

  sub() {
    this.myArray.removeAt(this.myArray.length - 1);
  }

  toggle() {
    this.showMe = !this.showMe;
  }

  get myArray(): FormArray {
    return this.form.get('myArray') as FormArray;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [defer](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/defer) it will produce an actual value for every new subscriber.

```
 this.data$ = defer(() =>
      this.myArray.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(this.myArray.value))
  );
```

[Forked Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-value?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you, it works !  Why should I need to use defer ?

Comment: When we subscribe valuechanges we will not get an actual value because it emits event only on value changes.